# Styling the SystemMenu

Tags: .net, wpf, styles, window, systemmenu

We have fully styled WPF Menus and ContextMenus in our Product. They are all implicit styles. But, what I found was that the System Menu (Alt + Space) displays a Menu that is not according to our Styles but instead displays the Windows Default Style. Is there any way to correct this Styling issue?

Comment: I'm afraid that this is not easy. That Menu is some kind of system menu and determined by the system. You can however try some work-around such as suppressing that menu and show your own styled menu. Even this work-around may require lot of WIN32 API calls and implementations for your own menu (to replace the default).

Comment: Our Window is a full fledged CustomWindow control (inherits WPF Window) and has custom styling and all. We do use Win32 APIs for some of its internal working. Can someone guide us in styling it, any article - I could not find any unfortunately ...

Comment: As I said it's not easy to style it ***directly***. I think when you can style it in WPF, you'll do the same in winforms. That means WPF cannot help you in this case (unless you use a work-around or style it ***indirectly***). I would choose a work-around because styling a WIN32 menu is not trivial.

Comment: Thank you...I'll try digging in some more on  WinForms styling ... :)